# Drill Down Through Opportunity Name Link

Tags: visualforce, controller

I want to add *Drill down functionality on Opportunity Name link*.. means when someone click on link then all the PRODUCT Will be display in new page which is added in single Opportunity.

Here is my Controller...But i am not understanding that where should i write Code in controller and VF Page for display List of Product.

**CONTROLLER :**

```
public class ListOfEditionOpportunity {
    public List<Edition__c> accList {get; set;} 
    public string SelectedEdition {get;set;}
    public List<Opportunity> opptyList {get; set;}
    List<OpportunityLineItem> myProduct{get;set;}
    public List<SelectOption> getEditionList(){
        List<SelectOption> listValue = new List<SelectOption>();
        listValue.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
        for(Edition__c L:accList){
            listValue.add(new SelectOption(l.id,l.name));
        }
        return listValue;
    }
    //Method to get Opportunity List Detail
    public List<Opportunity> getOpptyRecord(){
        List<Opportunity> myOpp = new List<Opportunity>([select id,Name,Account.name,
                                                         RecordType.Name,CloseDate,StageName,
                                                         Account_Owner_Formula__c,CreatedDate
                                                         from Opportunity WHERE Edition__r.id = :SelectedEdition ]);
     return myOpp;
    }
    public pageReference getDetails(){
        opptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
        for(Opportunity o:getOpptyRecord()){
            opptyList.add(o);
        }
             return null;
    }

       // Constructor of Class
    public ListOfEditionOpportunity(apexPages.StandardController controller){
        opptyList = new List<Opportunity>();
        accList = new List<Edition__c>([SELECT Id,Name FROM Edition__c]);
        SelectedEdition = '';
    }
}
```

**AND VF PAGE**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ListOfEditionOpportunity" tabStyle="Edition__c">

      <apex:form >
          <apex:pageBlock title="All Edition Details">

             <apex:outputLabel ><H2>Select Edition From the List</H2></apex:outputLabel>
                   &nbsp;&nbsp;
             <apex:selectList value="{!SelectedEdition}" size="1">
                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!EditionList}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport action="{!getDetails}" event="onchange" id="PBS2"/>
             </apex:selectList>
          </apex:pageBlock>

      <apex:pageblock >
      <apex:pageblockSection id="PBS1" title="List of Opportunity " collapsible="false"  columns="1" >
          <apex:pageblockTable value="{!opptyList}" Var="o" Width="100%">

              <apex:column HeaderValue="Action">

                  <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Edit,o.id)}"/>
                   &nbsp;
                  <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Delete,o.id)}" />   

              </apex:column>
              <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Name">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!o.id}">{!o.name}</apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Account Name">
                  <apex:outputLink value="/{!o.AccountId}">{!o.Account.Name}</apex:outputLink>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Opportunity Record Type" value="{!o.RecordType.Name}"/>
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Close Date" value="{!o.CloseDate}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Stage Name" value="{!o.StageName}"/>
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Account Owner Formula" value="{!o.Account_Owner_Formula__c}"/>
              <apex:column HeaderValue="Created Date" value="{!o.CreatedDate}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
      </apex:pageblockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Kindly Help me out from this requirement I'm new in Salesforce Development.
Please provide me some codes with example.
Thank you to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a command link in your existing opportunity listview page to redirect to your new page (viewProducts here).

VF page

```
<apex:commandLink value="View Products" action="{!redirectView}">
    <apex:param name="oppId" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!oppId}" />
</apex:commandLink>
```

Apex class - a method in your existing class

```
public pageReference redirectToProductView(){

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/viewProducts?Id='+oppId);
    pageRef.setredirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

The products list VF page (viewProducts here) should look like this

```
<apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!opptyProductList}" Var="opptyProduct" Width="100%">
        <apex:column HeaderValue="Action" value="{!opptyProduct.ProductCode}" />
    </apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Apex class to use as controller for VF page(viewProducts)

```
public class viewProductController{

    public List<OpportunityLineItem> opptyProductList {get;set;}    

    public viewProductController(){

        String oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        opptyProductList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Id,ProductCode
                                                            FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                                            WHERE OpportunityId =: oppId]);
    }
}
```

I have used only one field to display as of now. you can include as your requirement.

Comment: Hi, Sikha Baid, I implemented this code and Logic is cleared but after redirecting on new page Products is not showing or fetching and I saw in URL showing like = " https://c.cs84.visual.force.com/apex/productsListVfPage?Id=null "  id = null what should i do even i checked my SOQL Query in Query Editor that is working properly. Please clarify from this issue and thank you for your response.

Comment: place the code updates you have made. The parameter value is going null, just check the opportunity Id is queried and passing correctly.

Comment: Thank you Sikha Baid.. Finally i achieved my business requirement.